# Shadow Shader Chunks return errors

Tags: typescript, three.js, glsl

I'm trying to combine a basic toon shaded `ShaderMaterial` with threejs' built in shadow system (Some code was taken and modified from [here](http://www.realtimerendering.com/erich/udacity/exercises/unit3_toon_solution3.html)). From what I was able to find online, I discovered I'm supposed to use `ShaderChunks` when declaring the uniforms, vertex and fragment parts. I did so, and am getting errors whenever I set the Mesh's `recieveShadow` property to true. Here are the errors I'm getting:

#### Vertex Errors

```
THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() vertex ERROR: 0:72: 'worldPosition' : undeclared identifier 
ERROR: 0:72: 'assign' :  cannot convert from 'mediump 4X4 matrix of float' to 'mediump 4-component vector of float'
```

#### Fragment Errors

```
THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() fragment ERROR: 0:356: 'shadowMask' : undeclared identifier
ERROR: 0:356: 'assign' :  cannot convert from 'mediump 3-component vector float' to 'float'
```

I'm using the superpowers-game engine, which uses typescript. The threejs plugin for it is currently on r73. Here is my code (Still kind of messy, I'm just trying to get it all to work before polishing):

#### Shaders

```
const IslandVertexShader = `
    varying vec3 vNormal;
    varying vec3 vViewPosition;
    varying vec2 vUv;

    ${ THREE.ShaderChunk[ "shadowmap_pars_vertex" ] }

    void main() {

        vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal );
        vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
        vViewPosition = -mvPosition.xyz;
        vUv = uv;

        ${ THREE.ShaderChunk[ "shadowmap_vertex" ] }

        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

     }
`

const IslandFragmentShader = `
    uniform vec3 uMaterialColor;

    uniform vec3 uDirLightPos;
    uniform vec3 uDirLightColor;

    uniform float uKd;
    uniform float uBorder;

    varying vec3 vNormal;
    varying vec3 vViewPosition;
    varying vec2 vUv;

    ${ THREE.ShaderChunk[ "shadowmap_pars_fragment" ] }

    void main() {

        // compute direction to light
        vec4 lDirection = viewMatrix * vec4( uDirLightPos, 0.0 );
        vec3 lVector = normalize( lDirection.xyz );

        // diffuse: N * L. Normal must be normalized, since it's interpolated.
        vec3 normal = normalize( vNormal );
        //was: "float diffuse = max( dot( normal, lVector ), 0.0);",
        // solution
        float diffuse = dot( normal, lVector );
        if ( diffuse > 0.5 ) { diffuse = 1.0; }
        //else { diffuse = 0.5; };
        else if ( diffuse > -0.2 ) { diffuse = 0.7; }
        else { diffuse = 0.6; }

        //gl_FragColor = vec4( uMaterialColor.rgb, 1.0 );
        gl_FragColor = vec4( uKd * uMaterialColor * uDirLightColor * diffuse, 1.0 );

        ${ THREE.ShaderChunk[ "shadowmap_fragment" ] }

    }
`
```

#### Declaration

```
var sphere = new THREE.TorusKnotGeometry( 5, 1, 100, 16 );

var shader = new THREE.ShaderMaterial();
shader.uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.merge( [ THREE.UniformsLib[ "shadowmap" ], {

    uDirLightPos: { type: "v3", value: new THREE.Vector3( 0, 10, 0 ) },
    uDirLightColor: { type: "v3", value: new THREE.Vector3( 1, 1, 1 ) },
    uMaterialColor: { type: "v3", value: new THREE.Vector3( 0.5, 1, 1 ) },
    uKd: { type: "f", value: 1 }

} ] );

shader.vertexShader = IslandVertexShader;
shader.fragmentShader = IslandFragmentShader;
shader.lights = true; // Probably not needed
shader.needsUpdate = true; // Probably not needed either

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphere, shader );
mesh.castShadow = true;
mesh.receiveShadow = true; // The culprit
( <any>this.actor ).__inner.threeObject.add( mesh ); // Ignore this
```

Comment: Are you sure adding the ShaderChunks directly to the shader string like you are doing is going to work? Create a fiddle so it is easier to help you

Comment: Yes, the shader seems to check out. It only fails i recieveShadow is set to true. I'm not sure whether template strings are a typescript only thing, but ${} just concats a variable.

Comment: Going deeper, this seems to be an issue with the threejs version. I'm actually on r68. Things have changed since then regarding `shaderChunk` shadows. However, the issue was that I needed to add some other chunks to get it working.

Comment: oh, if you are on a version that old, maybe the examples [HERE](http://blog.2pha.com/experimenting-threejs-shaders-and-shadermaterial) will help

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was looking in the wrong file. I am in r73, and I figured out what was wrong. Writing an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it now after some digging. A lot of this isn't relevant if you're in a more updated version, but here is the now corrected code:

```
const IslandVertexShader = `
    varying vec3 vNormal;
    varying vec3 vViewPosition;
    varying vec2 vUv;

    ${ THREE.ShaderChunk[ "shadowmap_pars_vertex" ] }

    void main() {

        ${ THREE.ShaderChunk[ "begin_vertex" ] }

        vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal );
        vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
        vViewPosition = -mvPosition.xyz;
        vUv = uv;

        ${ THREE.ShaderChunk[ "worldpos_vertex" ] }
        ${ THREE.ShaderChunk[ "shadowmap_vertex" ] }

        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

    }
`

const IslandFragmentShader = `
    uniform vec3 uMaterialColor;

    uniform vec3 uDirLightPos;
    uniform vec3 uDirLightColor;

    uniform float uKd;
    uniform float uBorder;

    varying vec3 vNormal;
    varying vec3 vViewPosition;
    varying vec2 vUv;

    vec3 shadowMask = vec3( 1.0 );

    ${ THREE.ShaderChunk[ "shadowmap_pars_fragment" ] }


    void main() {

        // compute direction to light
        vec4 lDirection = viewMatrix * vec4( uDirLightPos, 0.0 );
        vec3 lVector = normalize( lDirection.xyz );

        // diffuse: N * L. Normal must be normalized, since it's interpolated.
        vec3 normal = normalize( vNormal );
        //was: "float diffuse = max( dot( normal, lVector ), 0.0);",
        // solution
        float diffuse = dot( normal, lVector );
        if ( diffuse > 0.5 ) { diffuse = 1.0; }
        //else { diffuse = 0.5; };
        else if ( diffuse > -0.2 ) { diffuse = 0.7; }
        else { diffuse = 0.6; }

        ${ THREE.ShaderChunk[ "shadowmap_fragment" ] }
        //gl_FragColor = vec4( shadowMask, 1.0 );
        gl_FragColor = vec4( shadowMask * uKd * uMaterialColor * uDirLightColor * diffuse, 1.0 );


    }
`
```

I needed to add the `begin_vertex` and `worldpos_vertex` chunks and define the vec3 shadowMask in the fragment shader, as well as use that when calculating the final `gl_FragColor`. I got this information by checking how the `BasicMaterial` shader worked in the threejs r73 commit ([link here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/f381aa4d302db2b1b39b5e4b8d672d01f985a447/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib.js#L12)).